# Proving that the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to $\dim(\text{null}(T-\lambda I)^{\dim V})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Without using induction, prove that the the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $$\dim (\text{null} (T-\lambda I)^{\dim V});$$ here, the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ refers to the number of times it appears on the diagonal of an upper triangular matrix.

**Attempt**:

Please note that the book this is taken from, *Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler*, hasn't yet introduced the Jordan form.

If an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is repeated $r$ times on the main diagonal of $M(T)$ (where $M(T)$ denotes the matrix associated with the linear mapping $T$), then $M(T - λ I )$ has $r$ zeroes on the main diagonal.

For example, suppose $\lambda = 3$ and $$M(T) =  \begin{pmatrix} 1&*&*&* \\ 0&\lambda&*&* \\ 0&0&\lambda&*\\0&0&0&2\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then, $$M(T-\lambda I) =  \begin{pmatrix} -2&*&*&* \\ 0&0&*&* \\ 0&0&0&*\\0&0&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

By Matrix Multiplication, any diagonal element of $M(T - λ I )^k$ would simply be it's $k^{th}$ power $........... (A)$

In a general case for any exponent $w$, due to point $(A)$ above, if there are $r$ zeroes on the diagonal element of $M(T - λ I )^w $:

> $$\phantom{(1)} \qquad \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^w ≤ r. \qquad (1)$$

Now, we know that for some exponent $m$ that

> \begin{multline} \text{null} (T - λ I )^0 \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^1 \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^2 \subset \cdots \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^m \\ \phantom{(2)} \qquad =\text{null} (T - λ I )^{m+1} = \cdots = \text{null}(T - λ I )^ { \dim V }. \qquad (2) \end{multline}

Hence,

> \begin{multline}\dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^0 = 0 < \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^1 <  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^2 <  \cdots <  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^m \\ \phantom{(3)} \qquad = \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^{m+1} = \cdots =  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^ { \dim V } \qquad (3)\end{multline}

(To know how this result came, please see page $165$ in the book [here](http://fetweb.ju.edu.jo/staff/EE/jrahhal/PDF/sc%20-%20Linear%20Algebra%20Done%20Right.pdf).)

> Now, $r \nless m$; suppose not: Even if the dimension increases by $1$ unit in each chain in $(3)$, at some stage we will get $\dim \text{null} (T - \lambda I )^p > r $  which will contradict point $(1)$. Hence $r \ge m$

How do I move ahead from here? I feel like I am close to the proof completion, but can't rule out the case $r > m$.

> What could happen if $r > m?$

Your help will be deeply appreciated in this regard. Please help me cross the final hurdle of this proof. Thank you very much.

Comment: The first and last diagonal entries of your formula for $M(T - \lambda I)$ seem to be incorrect.

Comment: Corrected $~~~$

Comment: Would you care to give a **precise** reference of where this exercise is from. It would seem to belong to chapter 8 of the book you linked to, but I could not find it among the exercises. On the other hand theorem 8.10 appears to state precisely what this question is about, so it is probably prior to that. Knowing precisely what you can be assumed to know here is crucial for answering the question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is indeed theorem 8.10 of Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler. But there, it's proved using induction.

Comment: So your question is really "I have found the following theorem in the book by Axler, and it is proved by induction (on the dimension). I am wandering if a proof without using induction is also possible." If you had just said that clearly (with a precise reference to the theorem) then **your** question would have been a lot clearer. As you formulated it (with imperative "prove"), it seems as if the book is asking to do this without induction, while in fact to the contrary the book chose to do it with induction (maybe for a good reason).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant actually. I missed out on conveying that I was attempting an alternate proof for the theorem which has been proved using induction in the book. It was accidental :)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I understand. Does that mean given the limited tool sets I have at the moment, it would be a little difficult for me to prove this?