# Algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $λ$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was going through a question posed on the expression for algebraic multiplicity of an eigen value $\lambda$ on this page :

[Proving that the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to $\dim(\text{null}(T-\lambda I)^{\dim V})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232926/proving-that-the-algebraic-multiplicity-of-an-eigenvalue-lambda-is-equal-to)

For convenience, I am copy pasting the argument posed by the OP here as follows:

" Without using induction, prove that the the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $$\dim (\text{null} (T-\lambda I)^{\dim V});$$ here, the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ refers to the number of times it appears on the diagonal of an upper triangular matrix.

**Attempt**:

Please note that the book this is taken from, *Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler*, hasn't yet introduced the Jordan form.

If an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is repeated $r$ times on the main diagonal of $M(T)$ (where $M(T)$ denotes the matrix associated with the linear mapping $T$), then $M(T - λ I )$ has $r$ zeroes on the main diagonal.

For example, suppose $\lambda = 3$ and $$M(T) =  \begin{pmatrix} 1&*&*&* \\ 0&\lambda&*&* \\ 0&0&\lambda&*\\0&0&0&2\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then, $$M(T-\lambda I) =  \begin{pmatrix} -2&*&*&* \\ 0&0&*&* \\ 0&0&0&*\\0&0&0&-1\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

By Matrix Multiplication, any diagonal element of $M(T - λ I )^k$ would simply be it's $k^{th}$ power $........... (A)$

In a general case for any exponent $w$, due to point $(A)$ above, if there are $r$ zeroes on the diagonal element of $M(T - λ I )^w $:

> $$\phantom{(1)} \qquad \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^w ≤ r. \qquad (1)$$

Now, we know that for some exponent $m$ that

> \begin{multline} \text{null} (T - λ I )^0 \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^1 \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^2 \subset \cdots \subset \text{null} (T - λ I )^m \\ \phantom{(2)} \qquad =\text{null} (T - λ I )^{m+1} = \cdots = \text{null}(T - λ I )^ { \dim V }. \qquad (2) \end{multline}

Hence,

> \begin{multline}\dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^0 = 0 < \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^1 <  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^2 <  \cdots <  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^m \\ \phantom{(3)} \qquad = \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^{m+1} = \cdots =  \dim \text{null} (T - λ I )^ { \dim V } \qquad (3)\end{multline}

(To know how this result came, please see page $165$ in the book [here](http://fetweb.ju.edu.jo/staff/EE/jrahhal/PDF/sc%20-%20Linear%20Algebra%20Done%20Right.pdf).)

> Now, $r \nless m$; suppose not: Even if the dimension increases by $1$ unit in each chain in $(3)$, at some stage we will get $\dim \text{null} (T - \lambda I )^p > r $  which will contradict point $(1)$. Hence $r \ge m$

How do I move ahead from here? I feel like I am close to the proof completion, but can't rule out the case $r > m$.

> What could happen if $r > m?$

Your help will be deeply appreciated in this regard. Please help me cross the final hurdle of this proof. Thank you very much. "

I have gone through the proof of this theorem in standard textbooks, but only by induction. I can't decipher if there exists a way forward after the attempt shown by the OP. Neither do I think the answer given by @Travis gives any clue.

Any thoughts on this attempt? Thanks!

Comment: For a linear operator given on some basis by a triangular matrix, any collection of equal diagonal entries is _not necessarily_ grouped together. The theory of Jordan normal forms will tell you that you _can_ achieve this additional condition (on an appropriate basis), but as you formulate the question, you might not be able to use that. Do you have an(other) argument to assume that they are grouped? If not you need to do without, which complicates reasoning.

Comment: There is very little in this question other than in the question you copy-pasted from. You are not satisfied with the answer at that question, which you have all the right to, but it is not really a reason to post a new question. So I'm going to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Please give me a moment. I will pen down my thoughts